# C# UWP packagemanager.UpdatePackageAsync Access denied exception

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm trying to update `appxbundle` by using `PackageManager`.

```
PackageManager packagemanager = new PackageManager();
await packagemanager.UpdatePackageAsync(
    new Uri(packageLocation), 
    null, 
    DeploymentOptions.ForceApplicationShutdown
);
```

But ended up by getting this exception:

> (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).

Comment: What rights have you added to your app? Does it run with elevated privileges?

Comment: I haven't added any rights or any other privileges to my app.

Comment: You're trying to create a package that forcibly closes an application before update. This ( from what I remember ) requires additional privileges. Was your application installed using Developer Mode?

Comment: You need to declare `packageManagement` capability for this to work. However this capability is part of [Restricted Capability List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations#restricted-capability-list). You can still sideload your app though.

Comment: @Mateusz. Yes the app is installed using developer mode.

Comment: @AVK. Previously i added packageQuery capability & now based on your comment i have added packageManagement capability too. Now the access denied exception is resolved. Thank you very very much :)

Comment: If your app is installed using Developer Mode you should be good using `DeploymentOptions.DevelopmentMode`

Comment: @San I'm glad I could be of help.